# Regex to match a doubles separated by one space only

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to check a match as the user enters values in the text box.

Valid values for the textbox are like this:

```
"-"

"-5.5"

"-5.5 6.5 7.5"
```

Invalid would be

```
"-5.5   6.5    "
```

Edit: ^there is more than one space between -5.5 and 6.5, but it doesn't show for some reason.

```
"3.5 "

^(-?)(\d+\.?\d?)\s?(-?\d+\.?\d?)
```

Keep in mind that the negative sign is the only special character, other than the decimal point, allowed in here.

Thanks.

Comment: what about your regex doesn't work?

Comment: @Gregory Dodd Will you accept integer or .55 or 55.?

Comment: What about  `1E3`? Side note: I'd vote for splitting on whitespace and than parsing doubles...

Comment: @Rhoit.. I was away at lunch. I have accepted an answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
^(-|-?\d+\.?\d?([ ]-?\d+\.?\d?)*)$
```

This will match either a single hyphen or any number of space-separated positive or negative numbers with an optional decimal point and at most one digit after it. This will allow values like `"5.5 6.5"` or `"-5.5 -6.5"` (your question didn't specify if it should match those or not)

You can test it [here](http://regexpal.com/?flags=gm&regex=%5E%28-%7C-%3F%5Cd%2B%5C.%3F%5Cd%3F%28%5B%20%5D-%3F%5Cd%2B%5C.%3F%5Cd%3F%29%2a%29%24&input=-%0A-5.5%0A-5.5%206.5%207.5%0A%0A-5.5%20%20%206.5%20%20%20%20).

---

**Update**

This will allow many more matches, but satisfies the new requirement of supporting every valid sequence as the user is typing. Of course, it allows even more, since it's impossible to determine the difference between invalid input and input which is merely incomplete (e.g. `-5 -`).

```
^(-?(\d+\.?\d?( |$)|$))*$
```

You can test it [here](http://regexpal.com/?flags=gm&regex=%5E%28-?%28?%3a%5Cd%2b%5C.?%5Cd?%28?%3a%20%7C%24%29%7C%24%29%29%2a%24&input=-%0A-5%0A-5%20%0A-5%20-%0A-5%20-5%0A-5%20-5.%0A-5%20-5.5%0A-5%20-5.5%20%0A-5%20-5.5%205%0A-5%20-5.5%205.%0A-5%20-5.5%205.6%0A%0A3%0A3.%0A3.5%0A3.5%20%0A3.5%20x).

Comment: I'd write the regular expression to match a decimal literal as `(-?\d+(\.\d+)?)`, which is to an that it is an integral part (consisting of an optional sign, followed by 1+ digits), followed by an optional fraction (consisting of a decimal point, followed by 1 or more digits). The whole regular expression then becomes `^(-|((-?\d+(\.\d+)?)(\x20(-?\d+(\.\d+)?))*))$`

Comment: Doing some more looking into this and I have found it won't work correctly for my needs. It is mostly correct, but it is checked onpropertychanged of the textbox. So in other words it needs to be able to handle lots of different things.

Comment: So I finally got back to working on this. This one works if the string is all finalized before the match is checked. however, this is being used for a textbox binding property that is fired OnPropertyChanged, not on LostFocus. So it doesn't allow me to enter certain digits.

So for example it needs to handle first typing `"-"`, then `"-5"`, then `"-5 "`, then `"-5 5"`. etc.... This one can't handle all of that. It won't allow `"-5 "`, so I can't even type anything after -5.

Comment: @GregoryDodd I would only do the validation once the user has completed input in the text field. Either that or use two separate patterns (something very simple like `^[ \d-]+$`). Otherwise how could you possibly know if the user input `-5.5 -` is invalid or they simply haven't finished typing out the next number.

Comment: Business wants the validation done in real time. I am guessing I will need to break it up and have a couple different patterns. One other problem this has is that you can't have the following `"-5 -5.5 5.6"` I assume that is because of the $ symbol. I tried removing that and it seems to cause it to ignore other restrictions, which I thought was odd. That said, it seems like this should be able to be tweaked to handle it checking every time a character is entered.

Comment: @g.t.w.d See my updated answer. I still think you'll need to do two validations. 1) to see if the input could *possibly* be valid while the user is typing, and 2) to check if the input was *actually* valid once the they're done typing.

Answer (score 4):

You can use this:

```
^-(?:\d+[.]\d+(?:[ ]\d+[.]\d+)*)?$
```

Explanation:

```
^   
  -                   // Match '-'
  (?:                 // An optional non-capturing group
      \d+[.]\d+       // Match pattern - 14.45
      (?:             // A 0 or more times repeating Non-capture group
         [ ]          // A space
         \d+[.]\d+    // Pattern matching - 14.56
      )*              
  )?    
$
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
^(-(\d+\.\d+)*([ ]\d+\.\d+)*)$
```

Comment: I think `^(-(\d\.\d[ ])*(\d\.\d))$` is same as of you.

Comment: I did not get you. Did you mean `^(-(\d\.\d[ ])*(\d\.\d))$` is equivalent to `^(-(\d+\.\d+[ ])*(\d+\.\d+))$`? Its not, `\d` will match only one digit, whereas `\d+` will match one or more digits.

Comment: But in the beginning you have written as `^(-(\d{1}\.\d{1}[ ])*(\d{1}\.\d{1}))$` That's why I said. Now it is not. :)